# Cytoscape can't add new label

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Is it possible to have (one?) more label for nodes?

I want to retrieve node Id, but not within Node Name.

Thx all

Comment: Finally i have found this solution:

Answer (score 0):

You could use the multiline-manual or multiline-auto style for labels. That way you can set the label to a string containing the labels with \n between them.

Comment: Thank you
You make me to the solution i needed

Answer (score 0):

**Finally i have found this solution.**

In var elements:

```
var elem = {
        data: {
            id: idE,
            name: name,
            label: "#"+id+ " | " + name
        }
```

In css node:

```
selector: 'node',
        style: {
            'content': 'data(label)'
```

So i can retrieve name or id separetly as usual, but showing more node information.

Thx all